# Terraform plan fails with "" is empty tuple

Tags: terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws, aws-devops

I am creating an api gateway endpoint and then adding an custom authorizer to it based on if the lambda function is present or not.

```
module "data_sources_api_report" {
  source = "..."

  pipeline_environment = var.pipeline_environment
  pipeline_vertical    = var.pipeline_vertical
  iam_boundary         = var.horizon_iam_boundary
  region               = var.aws_region
  allow_origin         = "*"

  is_with_vpc_link_connected = true
  vpc_link_id                = aws_api_gateway_vpc_link.datasource_vpc_link.id

  path_part                           = "devices"
  resource_endpoint_vpc_link_url_part = "api/v2/partitions/{partitionId}/report-datasource"
  request_path_parameters             = ["partitionId"]
  request_query_parameters            = []
  request_headers                     = []
  authorizer                          = var.enforcement_lambda_function_name == null ? null : aws_api_gateway_authorizer.authorizer[0].id

  rest_api_id            = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.reporting_services_api.id
  parent_resource_id     = aws_api_gateway_resource.http_resource_report-datasource_v2.id
  resource_http_method   = "GET"
  nlb_dns_name           = local.vpc_remote_state.datasource_load_balancer_dns_name
  integration_input_type = "HTTP_PROXY"

  tags = local.common_tags
}
```

Creating the api gateway authorizer

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_authorizer" "authorizer" {
  count = var.enforcement_lambda_function_name != null ? 1 : 0

  name                   = "enforcement_layer_auth_${random_string.random.result}"
  rest_api_id            = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.reporting_services_api.id
  authorizer_uri         = join(",", data.aws_lambda_function.authorizer_lambda_function.*.invoke_arn)
  authorizer_credentials = join("", aws_iam_role.invocation_role.*.arn)
  type                   = "REQUEST"

  authorizer_result_ttl_in_seconds = 0
  identity_source                  = join(",", ["method.request.header.Authorization", "context.httpMethod", "context.path"])
}
```

The error I am getting is this aws_api_gateway_authorizer.authorizer is empty tuple

```
Error: Invalid index
  on api_gateway.tf line 281, in module "data_sources_api_report":
 281:   authorizer                          = var.enforcement_lambda_function_name == null ? null : aws_api_gateway_authorizer.authorizer[0].id
    |----------------
    | aws_api_gateway_authorizer.authorizer is empty tuple
```

enforcement_lambda_function_name var has been defined

Comment: Have you verified that the authorizer is created?

Comment: Also, is the authorizer part of the module or not?

Comment: Hi, can you check the value of aws_api_gateway_authorizer.authorizer[0].id in terraform console? Also try using count. Index instead of 0 to test.